# How Print('Object') is executing before getData() function gets finished in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, async-await, future

I was Learning Async and Future Functions in Dart but I got confused because I still not get it like how print("object")  is compiled before getData() function because traditionally next Line is read by compiler once the before line or Function  is fully compiled/Executed . If I am making a Mistake Please correct me out , I am noob tbh

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
const Loading({super.key});

@override
State\<Loading\> createState() =\> \_LoadingState();
}

class \_LoadingState extends State\<Loading\> {
void getdata() async {
String parth = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
return 'parth';
});
print('Hey');
print(parth);
}

@override
int count = 0;
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
getdata();
print('object');
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// print(' Setstae vala + $count');
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Loading'),
),
body: ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {
setState(() {
count++;
});
},
child: Text('$count')),
);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, i see no 'Hey there' in your code

Comment: Print('Object') *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output should be like this:

1. object
2. Hey
3. parth

> because traditionally next Line is read by compiler once the before
> line or Function is fully compiled/Executed

Normaly, yes. But since you are using the async keyword in this case, it works a little differently.

What happens here:

You call getData first in your initState. In getData you have a future delayed in it, which you wait for with keywoard await. So it waits 3 seconds until you return 'parth' as a string. At the same time, however, it continues to run in your initState to return 'object'.

Answer (score 0):

`getdata` is a async method, you need to return `Future<void>` to await.

Now the `initState()` cant be async, you can create another method to await and place it here.

```dart
void newMethod() async {
  await getdata();
  print('object');
}
```

And place `newMethod()` inside initState.

Or you can use `.then`

```dart
 getdata().then((_) {
    print('object');
  });
```

Comment: Except that an async method inside initState (which cannot be async) almost never does what beginners think it will.  Generally, it's time to reach for FutureBuilder when that is needed.